# Converter string binária em int decimal em C

Tags: c, string, int, binary

Estou tentando converter uma string binária num inteiro decimal, mas não consigo achar onde meu código está errado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int decimal = 0;
    char bin[20];
    printf("Escreva um numero binario: ");
    scanf_s("%s", bin);

    int len = strlen(bin);    

    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        decimal =+  (bin[i] * pow(2, i));   // Multiplico o caracter da string por 2^i e somo em decimal.
    }
    printf("O numero binario correponde ao decimal: %d", decimal);

    return 0;
}
```

O output está dando um valor muito maior que o esperado...
Input: 01001
Output esperado: 9
Output recebido: 1506

Comment: Tenta debugar para analisar o problema - provavelmente está na linha onde tu eleva ao quadrado (`pow`)...

Comment: O `bin[i]` é uma string, sendo assim, em ASCII a letra "0" é 48 e "1" é 49.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que ao fazer  `bin[i] * pow(2, i)` você está fazendo `char * double`. Sendo que o `char` é um texto, e os textos de  "0" e "1" não são equivalentes à 0 e 1 numericos. Em ASCII o "0" (em texto) é 48, pode ver numa tabela de ASCII ([https://web.fe.up.pt/~ee96100/projecto/Tabela%20ascii.htm](https://web.fe.up.pt/%7Eee96100/projecto/Tabela%20ascii.htm)).

Uma forma de corrigir o problema aparentemente seria:

```
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        decimal +=  ((bin[i] - '0') * pow(2, i));
    }
```

O `- '0'` é equivalente à fazer `- 48`. Dessa forma o `49 - 48 = 1`. Mas, como os números são sempre bits e já são binários, poderia também usar:

```
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        decimal |= (bin[i] - '0') << i;
    }
```

Isso irá definir o bit (`1` ou `0`) na posição `i`. O `1` e `0`.

---

Obviamente, a quantidade maxima de bits está relacionado ao tamanho do `int`, que pode ser obtido usando `sizeof() * 8`, isso também assume que a entrada não contem caracteres inválidos (maiores/menores que 0 e 1, ou maiores do que a quantidade de bits).